# Adding CSS in Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, css

im trying to add a css class in my javascript code but when i preview it in the browser it dont seem to work

heres the code

```
<script>
var mydate=new Date()
var year=mydate.getYear()
if (year < 1000)
  year+=1900
var day=mydate.getDay()
var month=mydate.getMonth()
var daym=mydate.getDate()
if (daym<10)
  daym="0"+daym
var dayarray=newArray("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday",
                      "Friday","Saturday")
var montharray=newArray("January","February","March","April","May","June",
                        "July","August","September","October","November",
                        "December")
document.write(""+dayarray[day]+" "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+" "+year+"")
    .className = 'bigdate';
</script>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.bigdate{
  color:#03C;
}
```

Comment: `document.write().classname` doesn't make sense to me. Where do you have that from?

Comment: document.write doesn't return a node that can have a class added to it.

Comment: Instead of `var year=mydate.getYear()
if (year < 1000)
  year+=1900`, you can use [`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how `document.write()` works, it doesn't return a reference to the node(s) that it wrote.

Try...

```
document.write("<span class=\"bigdate\">"+dayarray[day]+" "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+" "+year+"</span>");
```

...or better still...

```
var span = document.createElement('span');
span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(dayarray[day]+" "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+" "+year+));
document.body.appendChild(span);
```

Comment: +1 for "or better still..." that doesn't use a sledgehammer (authority-wise) to kill a gnat.

Answer (score 1):

You should **not** use `document.write` to update the document. Update the document by setting the `innerHTML` property, or appending an element.

```
<div id="my-element"></div>
<script>
....
var elem = document.getElementById('my-element');
elem.innerHTML = dayarray[day]+" "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+" "+year;
elem.className = 'bigdate';
</script>
```

`className` is a property which refers to the `class` attribute. `document.write()` has no return value, so no properties. Even if you want to use `document.write()`, then you have to use HTML tags, and add `class="bigdate"`:

```
document.write('<div class="bigdate">' + ..... + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write(""+dayarray[day]+" "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+" "+year+"").className = 'bigdate';
```

Should be:

```
document.write("<div class='bigdate'>"+dayarray[day]+" "+daym+" "+montharray[month]+" "+year+"</div>").
```

You need to have an HTML element to have a class name.